# How can I replace the "." in a float with "_" in python?

Tags: python, string, replace

Python code (can't change this):

```
import numpy as np
        
for VALUES in np.arange(0.1, 0.3, 0.1):
    print("Value: %s" % (VALUES))
```

Output:

```
Value: 0.1
Value: 0.2
```

Desired output:

```
Value: 0_1
Value: 0_2
```

I am a beginner when it comes to python, and I'm struggling with this simple task. Is this possible with the replace() method? Do I need to create a new function that makes the replacement?

Comment: Your limitations are not clear. If you cannot make any changes, how are you going to perform such replacement?  Are you talking about a decorator?

Comment: Note: "The '_' option signals the use of an underscore for a thousands separator for floating point presentation types" so that format is super confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell given the limited information provided.

But if you want to make the replacement just for the code shown here you can do this:

```py
import numpy as np
        
for VALUES in np.arange(0.1, 0.3, 0.1):
    print("Value: %s" % (str(VALUES).replace(".", "_")))
```

But I am not sure what you mean when you say "can't change this".

Hope this gives a hint at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do, you need to convert the float to a string.

```
float_value = 0.1
string_value = str(float_value)
```

Then you can use the replace() function

```
string_value = string_value.replace(".","_")
```